# whitespace next to header columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using:

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

When the last of my table column header ends, there is a ugly white space until the end of the table. That is because my background for the table is set to BLACK. How can I get rid of the white space?

Comment: ah that famous "rectangle", which is a dead giveaway that the app is a Java Swing app using JTable...  In your specific case you may probably set it to black (like the rest of your table) but you'd still have an "ugly black rectangle".  If you want something "better" than that it can quickly get **very** messy.  Here's a blog entry (from an author who then went to work at Apple if I'm not mistaken) about *"Creating a better JTable"*: http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/category/ui/page/3/

Comment: @TacticalCoder's comment is much better than arooaroo's "answer". It seems as if their placement should have been reversed -- that the comment above should have been an answer since it is more than simply the listing of a link as arroarro's reply is.

Comment: @TacticalCoder thanks for the link. Was exactly what i needed. Have u used the BetterJTable with a sort of freeze pane (like excel) implementation? I am struggling to get the striped layout to work on both jtables

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly I believe it's similar to the one described and solved here by Santhosh Kumar: [JTable becomes uglier with AUTO_RESIZE_OFF](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/jtable_becomes_uglier_with_auto)